# HTTP time out not working for Spring - http

Tags: spring, timeout, httpclient

While upgrading to Spring 4, we were obliged to change the context configuration of http invoker to match http-client 4.4.9 and http-core 4.5.5 as follows:

```
    <bean id="requestConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig" factory-method="custom">
    <property name="socketTimeout" value="${connection.timeout}" /> 
    <property name="connectTimeout" value="${connection.timeout}" />
    <property name="staleConnectionCheckEnabled" value="${connection.doStaleCheck}"/> 
    <property name="connectionRequestTimeout" value="${connection.poolTimeout}" />
</bean>

<bean id="requestConfig" factory-bean="requestConfigBuilder" factory-method="build" />

<bean id="httpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder" factory-method="create">
    <property name="defaultRequestConfig" ref="requestConfig" />
    <property name="maxConnTotal" value="${connection.maxActive}" />
    <property name="maxConnPerRoute" value="${connection.maxActive}" />
</bean>

<bean id="httpClientBld" factory-bean="httpClientBuilder" factorymethod="build" />
```

However, while testing, the sockect time out and connection time out doesnt seem to be working correctly... it always waits around 1000 ms for the connection timeout and 60000 for the socket time out instead of the configured values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking further into this issue, it turned out to be a problem from Spring 4 not from http client jar and only occurring when the time out values are passed by context configuration XML file. As a solution, we pr grammatically set the time out values

```
 CloseableHttpClient httpClient = (CloseableHttpClient) context.getBean("httpClientBld");
  HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor executor = new HttpComponentsHttpInvokerRequestExecutor(httpClient);

  HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean httpInvokerProxyFactoryBean = new HttpInvokerProxyFactoryBean();

  httpInvokerProxyFactoryBean.setServiceInterface(InterfaceClass.class);
  httpInvokerProxyFactoryBean.setServiceUrl(endpoint);
  httpInvokerProxyFactoryBean.setHttpInvokerRequestExecutor(executor);
  httpInvokerProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

  this.cainServer = (InterfaceClass) httpInvokerProxyFactoryBean.getObject();
```

In the context we just used:

> ```
> <bean id="requestConfigBuilder" class="org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig" factory-method="custom">
>     <property name="socketTimeout" value="${connection.timeout}" /> 
>     <property name="connectTimeout" value="${connection.timeout}" />
>     <property name="staleConnectionCheckEnabled" value="${connection.doStaleCheck}"/> 
>     <property name="connectionRequestTimeout" value="${connection.poolTimeout}" />
> </bean>
> <bean id="requestConfig" factory-bean="requestConfigBuilder" factory-method="build" />
> <bean id="httpClientBuilder" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder" factory-method="create">
>     <property name="defaultRequestConfig" ref="requestConfig" />
>     <property name="maxConnTotal" value="${connection.maxActive}" />
>     <property name="maxConnPerRoute" value="${connection.maxActive}" />
> </bean>
> <bean id="httpClientBld" factory-bean="httpClientBuilder" factory-method="build" />
> ```

where the values are passed from Java code.
Note that one issue is still remaining, it is that the connect time out is still 100 ms and not the configured one. But this issue is from http client jar not from Spring 4.